# Cannot find module 'glob' when running node.js file and selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to whip up a quick Selenium Webdriver in JavaScript.

I have it set up:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
   .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
   .build();
```

I have installed selenium-webdriver already. I think the issue is coming from Grunt. I have looked all over for answers, but I have not found a working solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install your modules when they are said to be 'not found'

```
npm install glob
```